# starting mongod service in windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, cmd

guys i am trying to start `mongod` service with authentication , it ask me to give the database path , so i pass a config parameter with the following , putting in mind that i am already in the directory of the `mongod` service `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin`

```
mongod --auth --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg"
```

as the configuration file has the `dbpath` , but `cmd` get stuck

here is the configuration file

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: What makes you think CMD is stuck. If it starts your program it is not.

Comment: Define "cmd get stuck". Mongod is a daemon process, so it won't exit unless you tell it to.

Comment: Please show us your config file

Comment: Do you get any error message

Comment: i know it is stuck as through services.msc mongo service is still stopped and i could start the shell.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit actually no error appears

Comment: Check logs in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log\mongod.log If the mongod seems to hang, then most likely the service is running fine.

Comment: _"services.msc mongo service is still stopped"_ - yes, if you manually start the process from the command line, you're not starting the Windows Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these to your config file:

```
processManagement:
  windowsService:
    serviceName: MongoDB
    displayName: MongoDB
    description: MongoDB Server - Standalone DB

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Then you can install the service with this command:

```
mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg" --install
```

After you created the service, you cas start either from "Service" or by command line with

```
net start MongoDB
```

In order to stop/remove a service (entirely!) run

```
net stop MongoDB
sc config MongoDB start=disabled
mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg" --remove
rmdir /S "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data"
```

Comment: According to their comments, there is already a MongoDB service present in services.msc.

Comment: Then the answer is obvious, you cannot have two services with the same name or listening to the same port (27017). You have to remove the service, see my update

Comment: NB, usually it is not best practice to put config files or program data in "C:\Program Files\..." Typically this goes to (hidden) C:\ProgramData or a user profile